# add and remove attr when a radio button is checked

Tags: jquery

html:

```
<input type="text" id="txtExternalLink" style="display:none"/>
```

in radio button

```
$('#rdbExternalLink').bind("click", function() {
    $('#txtExternalLink').removeAttr("style");
});
```

its work n text box is appear. But

```
$('#rdbPages').bind("click", function() {
    $('#txtExternalLink').addAttr('style="display:none"');
});
```

its not work.Plz help to find correct way to do this.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Craigs method will work, although what you're doing is equivalent to the built in .hide() and .show() methods:

```
$('#rdbExternalLink').bind("click", function() {
    $('#txtExternalLink').show();
});

$('#rdbPages').bind("click", function() {
    $('#txtExternalLink').hide();
});
```

Comment: My answer was to fix his problem.

Comment: Sorry that was kind of snarky...just having a rough morning. Cheers!

Comment: No worries, just giving an alternative method.

Answer (score 1):

$('#txtExternalLink').attr("style", "display:none");

Here is the documentation http://api.jquery.com/attr/